# CustomAuthStateProvider does not redirect to login after user's authentication expires

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-5, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app with a custom implementation of the AuthenticationStateProvider that uses a token service to verify the user's JWT. It looks like this:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{

    private ITokenService TokenService;
    private TokenValidationParameters Validations;

    public CustomAuthStateProvider(ITokenService tokenService, TokenValidationParameters validations)
    {
        TokenService = tokenService;
        Validations = validations;
    }

    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var token = TokenService.TryGetToken();

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var principal = handler.ValidateToken(token, Validations, out var _);

            var identity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)
                ? new ClaimsIdentity()
                : new ClaimsIdentity(ServiceExtensions.ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "JWT");

            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        };
    }
}
```

In the App.razor component I'm using AuthorizeRouteView along with a slightly customized implementation of the [RedirectToLogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#redirecttologin-component-2) component to redirect the user to the login page whenever they are unauthorized:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
  <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
      <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <NotAuthorized>
          <UnauthorizedRedirect />
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
      <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <p class="text-muted text-center">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
      </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
  </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

This works just fine for any initial state of the application - if the user navigates to the page and is already authenticated, they get right in; if not, they are redirected to the login page. However, if the user sits idle long enough that their token expires and then starts clicking around in the app again, no redirect occurs. Instead, even when the token validation fails and the CustomAuthStateProvider returns an anonymous state, the user is still free to navigate around the app. If the user then refreshes the page, the redirect to login occurs as expected, but not before.

I may be misunderstanding the behavior of the AuthorizeRouteView component or of the AuthenticationStateProvider, but my expectation would be that the moment a user is determined to be unauthenticated, the NotAuthorized component would be invoked and the user would be redirected. Is there something extra I need to be doing here to make it work thusly?

Comment: Have you discovered the solution of this problem? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Blazor Server apps work in a different way to other ASP.NET apps. On initial page load a "circuit" is created using a SignalR websockets connection and the subsequent transfer of data happens over this.

You can see this in your browser dev tools, navigating around your app changes the URL in the browser but doesn't trigger a page reload.

The user / circuit is authenticated on page load and not on every communication over the channel.

To solve this problem you need to change your `CustomAuthStateProvider` to inherit from `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider`. This itself inherits from `AuthenticationStateProvider` so your existing overridden method and code for validating the token will still work.

You will need to implement a `RevalidationInterval` property as a `TimeSpan` and override `ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync`. This overridden method will get called according to the `RevalidationInterval` and allows you to check that the token is still valid.